Create files on demand (lazy file creation) in linux
For a gui service I want to create icons on demand. Is it possible that one service requests a certain file, for example icon_vscode_64x64.png but the read call is blocked until another service actually creates that file on the fly? I heard about fanotify but I'm not sure if it can actually create the files, or if it's just filling the file content. As you can see the dimensions of the icon (64x64 in this case) are also part of the filename which could be dynamic! So the generator needs to parse the filename to get additional information.
Essentially I'm trying to coerce filenames into some kind of a query to another service.

If you want some service to generate the file, have you considered having the client ask the service for the file content and skip the filesystem?

@AndyDalton That's also a good idea. However, this would probably require me to write some sort of client-server infrastructure for this service. It would be nice if I could get around that.

A possible solution exists via a
FUSE filesystem that transparently
runs a command whenever you access a file.
There are many fuse filesystems that do this sort of thing, for example
cmdfs, but I don't know of one that
does not need you to start from a list of filenames, or an existing tree of
files.
However, it is relatively simple to create your own FUSE implementation,
for example using the Python library
fusepy. This may be available on your
system as a package of the same name (on Fedora 38 it was package
python3-fusepy).
I created a file mfuseruncmd.py with contents:
#!/usr/bin/python3
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/783810/119298
import sys, time, errno, subprocess
from stat import S_IFDIR, S_IFREG
from fuse import FUSE, Operations, FuseOSError # package python3-fusepy

cached = {} # dict of filenames we have already run cmd for

def runcmd(*cmd):
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True)
    if result.returncode: print(*cmd,"failed", file=sys.stderr)
    return result.stdout

class MyFS(Operations):
    now = time.time()

    def getattr(self, path, fh=None):
        if path == '/':
            return dict(st_mode=(S_IFDIR | 0o755),
                        st_nlink=2,
                        st_ctime=self.now,
                        st_mtime=self.now,
                        st_atime=self.now)
        else:
            return dict(st_mode=(S_IFREG | 0o444),
                        st_nlink=1,
                        st_size=1,
                        st_ctime=self.now,
                        st_mtime=self.now,
                        st_atime=self.now)

    def readdir(self, path, fh):
        if path == '/':
            return ['.', '..', 'foo']
        else:
            raise FuseOSError(errno.ENOENT)

    def open(self, path, flags):
        if not path in cached:
            cached[path] = runcmd("echo",path,time.asctime())
        return 0

    def read(self, path, size, offset, fh):
        return cached[path][offset:offset+size]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mountpoint = sys.argv[1]
    FUSE(MyFS(), mountpoint, foreground=True, direct_io=True, nonempty=True)

Note that all indentation must use spaces only, no tabs. Make the file executable with chmod a+x.
Then run it (NOT as root) providing some existing directory on which to
mount the FUSE, eg
mkdir /tmp/myfs
./mfuseruncmd.py /tmp/myfs

Your login id may need to be in the fuse group to have permission to use fuse.
Now, if I ls the directory it shows a file foo, but I can also ls any
other filename, such as /tmp/myfs/somefile and it also exists.
If I cat the file, an echo command is run with the filename and date, and we see that as
the file contents.
$ ls -l /tmp/myfs/
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1 Sep 20 17:40 foo
$ ls -l /tmp/myfs/somefile
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1 Sep 20 17:40 /tmp/myfs/somefile
$ cat /tmp/myfs/somefile
/somefile Fri Sep 20 17:41:04 2024

To unmount the fuse, simply interrupt the Python program.
This is a proof of concept, with several potential problems. Please address any problems in separate specific posts, one per problem, possibly on stackoverflow.com if they are about programming.
